# RPM --queryformat FILEMD5S checksum is different than md5sum of machine

Tags: redhat, rpm, sles, checksum, md5

The RPM man page says:

> The FILEMD5S Tag The FILEMD5S tag is used to display the MD5 checksum
> for each of the files that comprise the package.
>
> Array: Yes (Size: One entry per filemd5s)
>
> Used with modifiers: N/A

But when run with, it gives a different MD5 Checksum than the one generated by the `md5sum` library.
Example:

```
host:~/test-packages # /bin/rpm -qp --queryformat '%{NAME}\t%{VERSION}\t%{RELEASE}\t%{FILEMD5S}\n' gcc5a-a.rpm
gcc5    5.3.1+r233831   12.1    2527984aaccbeb6f5f823c137786f1f8
host:~/test-packages # md5sum gcc5a-a.rpm
9fa64d911743a605e45857bdecac0174 gcc5a-a.rpm
```

Is there any tag to get the information about the file (`gcc5a-a.rpm` in this case) to compare with the actual file?